# Why is it impossible to have a static method in the subclass with the same signature as in parent class?

Tags: java

Why is it impossible to have a static method in the subclass with the same signature as in parent class?

```
class Parent {
    public final static void fun() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {        
    // doesn't compile! 
    public static void fun() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}
```

I just want to find out why they allow final modifier here? We all know that static methods belong to a class and not to object, so it is impossible to override the method in the subclass. So as for me `final` in redundant here.

Comment: you can redefine static method in subclass. +1 to @Michael's answer to pointing exact reason of compilation failure.

Answer (score 2):

You declared that method as `final`, which means you sealed it. A `final` method cannot be redefined by a subclass. Per Oracle,

> You use the final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method cannot be overridden by subclasses

Comment: this is true for instance method, but not for class methods.

Comment: @user3552363 Read the duplicate question. For class methods, `final` prevents _hiding_ the parent class' method.